# Eliminar Fotos Tomadas por mi App Móvil

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

estoy desarrollando una app Móvil en que toma fotos para Luego mandarlas, el problema esta en que no se como le haría para que el Botón Cancelar elimine la foto tomada,
estoy utilizando C# Xamarin y Xam.Plugin.Media para trabajar con la cámara y las fotos que toma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre que podes asociar un Event Handler al evento 'Clicked' del botón Cancelar. En el event handler, usar el método 'Delete' de la clase 'MediaFile' para eliminar la foto.

Un ejemplo:

```
using Xam.Plugin.Media;

// ...

// Crear boton
Button cancelarButton = new Button();
cancelarButton.Text = "Cancelar";

// Asociar Event Handler al evento 'Clicked' del botón cancelar
cancelarButton.Clicked += async (sender, args) => {
    // tomar foto con Media.Plugin
    MediaFile photo = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync();

    // chequear si la foto fue tomada con éxito
    if (photo != null) {
        // borro la foto
        photo.Delete();
    }
};
```